# route display 404 when upgrade asp.net mvc 3 to mvc 5

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

Hi I have a problem when upgrade my project from asp.net mvc 3 to mvc 5

my code is

```
         routes.MapRoute(
           "Song", // Route name
           "{songid}.song", // URL with parameters
           new
           {
               controller = "Song",
               action = "Song",
           });
```

When I run project iis  display 404 error but in asp.net mvc 3 it work fine.
Any idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now I found my mistake is forget to  change

```
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
```

in web.config

Comment: How did that fix it??

Answer (score 0):

Does your code look kind of like this?

```
public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Song",
            url: "{songid}.song",
            defaults: new { controller = "Song", action = "Song",
                    /*id = UrlParameter.Optional*/ }
        );
        routes.MapRoute(
            "Default",                                              // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}",                           // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = "" }  // Parameter defaults
        );
    }

    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        /// THE IMPORTANT PART
        RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, every another route config is work but only url like this "http://localhost:49625/Right-Here-Waiting-For-You__Richard-Marx.song " is not work